# Non-compact extremal Kähler spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I want to ask about a generalisation of the Calabi functional to non-compact Kähler spaces. My interest is mostly in Kähler surfaces, so I will assume real dimension $4$. In my work, I have found an explicit example **\eqref{4}** of non-compact geometry satisfying the variational equation, but with scalar curvature not being a holomorphic potential.

**My main question is:**

- How can one introduce a generalisation of Calabi functional for non-compact geometries? In particular, how to introduce the boundary terms to make the functional well-defined?

Also, maybe it is worth a separate question, but the example **\eqref{4}** was found as a solution to some generalisation of the extremality equation
$$
\mathcal{D}^* \mathcal{D} R + \frac{2}{3} \nabla^2 \operatorname{pf}(\mathcal{R}) = 0
$$
with $\mathcal{D}$ defined in **\eqref{3}**.

- Can this equation come from some functional? Is there some geometric intuition behind this equation? (It was introduced with physical motivation in mind.)

### Recap

E. Calabi has defined a functional for a compact Kähler manifold $(M, g, \omega, J)$ with a Kähler form $\omega$ in a Kähler class $\Omega$
$$
\operatorname{Ca} (\omega) = \int_M R^2(\omega) \omega^2 \,, \qquad \forall \omega \in \Omega \,. \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Here $R(\omega)$ is the scalar curvature with respect to $\omega$. The *extremal* Kähler surfaces are defined as the extrema of this functional, i.e. they satisfy the differential equation on curvature
$$
\frac{1}{2}\nabla^4 R + \nabla^m \left( R_{mn} \nabla^n R \right) = 0 \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
which is obtained from the variation of **\eqref{1}**. Here $\nabla$ is a Levi-Civita connection and $R_{mn}$ is the Ricci tensor; I am using Riemannian indices $m,n = 1, \dotsc, 4$.

The equation **\eqref{2}** can be seen as a trace of the square of the Lichnerowicz operator acting on $R$:
$$\tag{3}\label{3}
\frac{1}{2}\nabla^4 R + \nabla^m \left( R_{mn} \nabla^n R \right) = g^{i \bar{\jmath}} g^{k \bar{l}}\nabla_{i} \nabla_{\bar{\jmath}} \nabla_{k} \nabla_{\bar{l}} R = \mathcal{D}^* \mathcal{D} R 
$$
where $i,j,k,l=1,2$ are complex indices. This implies that on *compact* extremal Kähler spaces the scalar curvature is a holomorphic potential
$$
0 = \int_M \mathcal{D}^* \mathcal{D} R = \int_M |\mathcal{D} R|^2 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \nabla^{\bar{i}} \nabla^{j} R = 0.
$$
In particular, holomorphic potential $R$ implies that $J d R$ is a Killing field.

### An example of a non-compact extremal Kähler surface

I have found the example of a non-compact geometry satisfying the variational equation, but with scalar curvature not being a holomorphic potential.
\begin{gather*}
\tag{4}\label{4}
g = \dfrac{\rho d \rho^2}{F(\rho)}+\dfrac{\rho d \eta^2}{G(\eta)}+ \dfrac{F(\rho)}{\rho} \left(d\psi + \eta d\phi \right)^2 + \rho G(\eta) d \phi^2, \\
\omega = d (\rho (d\psi + \eta d\phi)),
\end{gather*}
i.e. the geometry is biaxisymmetric with $\phi$, $\psi$ are angular coordinates, and functions
$$
F(\rho) = \rho^2 , \quad G(\eta) = (1-\eta^2) (a_0 + a_1 \eta)
$$
where $a_0$, $a_1$ are constants. The scalar curvature is given by
$$
R = - \dfrac{F'' + G''}{\rho},
$$
so it is simple to check that $R$ is not a holomorphic potential. Furthermore, the geometry is not smooth at $\rho=0$ where the scalar curvature diverges.

The geometry belongs to the class of Calabi-type geometries, identified in [Apostolov, Calderbank, and Gauduchon - The geometry of weakly selfdual Kahler surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104233), and possesses a hamiltonian 2-form.

Also, notice that the pfaffian of the Ricci form is harmonic!
$$\tag{5}\label{5}
\nabla^2 \,\operatorname{pf} (\mathcal{R}) = \nabla^2 \left( \lvert\mathit{Ric}\rvert^2 - \frac{1}{2} R^2 \right) = 0
$$
where pfaffian is defined as $\operatorname{pf} (\psi) = 2 \star (\psi \wedge \psi)$.

Finally, this metric is also important for physics, see e.g., [Lucietti, Ntokos, and Ovchinnikov - On the uniqueness of supersymmetric AdS(5) black holes with toric symmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.00896) where it was identified with a building block of a near-horizon geometry of supersymmetric black holes.